# Forcing browser to download a file rather than caching

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a javascript file which internally calls a function to load an xml file.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    urlVal ="web/help.xml";
  }


The javaxcript is versioned so that the browser always loads it instead of 
caching it
    "./js/help_min.js?ver=${verNumber}"
```

I am facing an issue where browser downloads the latest js file but has cached help.xml included in js file.
    is there a way that the browser will always load latest "hepl.xml" rather than caching it.

Comment: Have you tried the  urlVal + '?' + Math.random().toString().replace(/\./,'') trick?

Answer (score 1):

The proper apporach would be to fix the backend to send headers telling the browser not to cache the data (see i.e. [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/1235698)). But if you cannot do that, make the request unique each time, i.e.

```
"./js/help_min.js?ver=${verNumber}&random=${something_random}"
```

where `something_random` value of `random` can be i.e. current time stamp (with millis). That way your request will not match the cache entry enforcing fetch on each request.

PS: you seem to also have design flaw, as by logic using the same `${verNumber}` should return the same data, hence caching would be more than welcome to reduce the traffic and speed up loading time.